# Too much cardamom in apple butter

Tags: seasoning

I put too much cardamom in the applesauce that I'm cooking down to make apple butter. Will the cardamom flavor mellow as the sauce cooks down or should I add more applesauce to dilute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardamon gets MORE pronounced as a sauce cooks down. Definitely add more applesauce.

Comment: I ended up letting it cook down as it was. You're right, it did become more pronounced but as the other spices did and the sugars concentrated the flavor became more balanced. It's still a bit too much cardamom for my taste but everyone else in the house thinks it's delicious.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked out for the most part. :)